# Numpy Matrix not flattening

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am trying a flatten a Numpy array but flatten, ravel, and hstack are not doing it. I need to be able to create a Pandas series from the array, but I can't seem to get it flat for Pandas to accept:

```
print(type(centroids))
# <class 'numpy.matrix'>

print(centroids.shape)
# (5, 9328)

centroid = centroids[i]
centroid = np.hstack(centroid)

print(centroid)
# [[ 0.98487911  0.7483803  11.80978353 ...  0.97687837  0.21988038
   3.33842549]]  <-- still enclosed by two brackets

print(centroid.shape)
# (1, 9328)

centroid = pd.Series(centroid, name='value') <-- throws exception: Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: pd.Series(centroid[0], name='value')    <- does this help

Comment: `centroid = centroids[i]` would be sufficient.

Comment: @KevinWelch unfortunately no, I tried it and it didn't work. Even if it did, I'm looking for a matrix-based approach...not an iterative one. Thanks though.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that centroid is a np.matrix, not an array. Your code will work if you simply change the last line to:

```
centroid = pd.Series(np.array(centroid).ravel(), name='value')
```